# Why does namedtuple._make check the return value's length?

Tags: python-3.x, namedtuple

Overriding the length method on `namedtuple` objects in Python is a fair bit more tedious than you might expect. The naive approach,

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Rule(namedtuple('Rule', ['lhs', 'rhs'])):
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.rhs)

r = Rule('S', ['NP', 'Infl', 'VP'])
new_r = r._replace(lhs='CP') # raises a TypeError
```

doesn't work. If you inspect the actual source code of the class (which is available as the `_source` attribute), you can see that `_make` (which `_replace` calls and which raises the error) is implemented like this:

```
@classmethod
def _make(cls, iterable, new=tuple.__new__, len=len):
    'Make a new Rule object from a sequence or iterable'
    result = new(cls, iterable)
    if len(result) != 2:
        raise TypeError('Expected 2 arguments, got %d' % len(result))
    return result
```

Interestingly, it checks to make sure that the length of the return value is 2. This makes it more difficult to override the `__len__` method on the tuple because `_make` will complain if it returns a value with a length other than 2.

It's possible to prevent this behavior by passing a "`len`" function that always returns 2 to `_make`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Rule(namedtuple('Rule', ['lhs', 'rhs'])):
    def _make(self, *args, len=lambda _: 2, **kwargs):
        return super()._make(*args, len=len, **kwargs)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.rhs)

r = Rule('S', ['NP', 'Infl', 'VP'])
new_r = r._replace(lhs='CP') # fine
```

My question is, why is this length check necessarily in the first place, and is it safe to override `_make` so it doesn't do it?

Comment: "Overriding the length method on namedtuple objects in Python is a fair bit more tedious than you might expect" - why would you do that? It seems like a terrible idea that would cause all kinds of bugs, even besides this bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_make` checks the return value's length because namedtuples are fixed-length, and `_make` has to enforce that. If it didn't, you could do

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
p1 = Point._make([1, 2, 3])
p2 = Point._make([1])
```

and get a Point with no `y` and a Point with an extra entry dangling off the end.

`_make` can't check the argument's length, because the argument could be an arbitrary iterable that doesn't support `len`, so the return value's length is the most convenient thing to check.

Do not override `_make` to bypass this check. Your object is far enough from the concept of a namedtuple - heck, far enough from the concept of a tuple - that you shouldn't be using namedtuple or any tuple subclass at all. Just write a regular class.